# file explorer not showing database and DDMS perspective is blank

Tags: android

I am using this code to create a database file but the file is not showing in the file explorer or DDMS. I am just creating a file and not implementing any thing

```
public class TimeTrackerOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public TimeTrackerOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, "database.db", null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

i have also included this in my activityfile

```
 TimeTrackerOpenHelper openHelper = new TimeTrackerOpenHelper(this ,"database.db", null, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The DB is not created until you call `getReadableDatabase` or `getWritableDatabase`. The constructor of `SQLiteOpenHelper` just stores the DB name and version in internal fields but does not yet create the DB file.